# How to load scripts via ajax when monaco editor is used

Tags: ajax, monaco-editor

When I use monaco editor in a web app, the loader causes previously defined ajax script loads to no longer load.  See example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8UdXJK?p=preview)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js',
    dataType: 'script'
  }).done(function() {
    console.log('Vue', typeof Vue)
  })      
</script>
```

In this example, Vue is undefined, removing the loader.js tag, Vue is no longer undefined and it logs dev mode message to the console

I have tried loading as text and calling eval, eval.call with context, creating a script tag and appending, vanilla ajax call without jquery, using require(src) and the loader seems to be aggressively trapping all script loads.

I have an application that has been using the ace editor and am trying to switch out to monaco.  The application is interactive, user writes queries and script and displays results.  From the results, the user could make a selection which could call another query to update results.

Answer (score 1):

The monaco `loader.js` is a small AMD loader - so use this:

```
require(['https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js'], function(theVue) {
  console.log('the Vue is ' + theVue);
})
```

See the first part of the vue source file - it checks for AMD and inits another way if present.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful information.  The real answer that I ended up going with was using monaco in an iframe to isolate the loader and keep the ajax call working as is